# Regex for specific problem

Tags: regex

I'm not very familiar to regex and even not able (maybe too tired?) to use this silly newby issue:

I need a regex, that allows any combination of numbers, letters (lower and upper case) and the underscore _

BUT: The beginning of this regex shall be fix and defined in my source code::

```
ABC_h2u3h4l
ABCijij4i5oi4j5
ABCABC
```

Here the piece `"ABC"` always has to be at the leading position.

Can someone give me a hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
^ABC[a-zA-Z0-9_]*$
```

Comment: I think that the regex should have a `^` at the beginning. Otherwise it won't guarantee that the string starts with `ABC`. It would match a string such as `123ABC`.

Answer (score 3):

that's the whole regex:

```
^ABC\w+
```

Comment: The ABC must match at the beginning of the line.  This will match anywhere.

Comment: Not necessarily (even without the `^`) - for example, in Python `re.match()` always anchors the match at the start of the string. But I'd add a `$` at the end, or the regex will also return True on a partially matched string.

Comment: @Tim: it's not clear from the question whether there is a single multi-line string given and every line should match (which with my regex would require `re.M` flag) or it's a series of string which could be matched with `re.match` (with or without the `^` anchor).

Answer (score 3):

Something like this?

```
^ABC\w+$
```